# PayPal recurring payment code integration

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing

I am new in PayPal integration. I need monthly PayPal recurring payment for users. I already have instant payment working with this method:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="form_paypal" id="paypal_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount"  value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="USA" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value='<?php echo $custom;?>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value= "Anonymous"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="User"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="payer_email" value="customer@example.com"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123" / >
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test.co Services" / >
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://test.co/pg_return.php" / >
    <input type="submit" value="Pay" name="pay" id="paypal_submit">
</form>
```

What do I need to change to integrate recurring payment in my panel? Please help me! If needed I will provide more info!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, here's how to set up subscription/recurring payment using the same method:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="form_paypal" id="paypal_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="a3"  value="<?php echo $amount; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M" >
    <input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1" >
    <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1" >
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value= "Anonymous"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="User"  />
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123" / >
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test.co Services" / >
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://test.co/pg_return.php" / >
    <input type="submit" value="Pay" name="pay" id="paypal_submit">
</form>
```

Note that I have made several changes. "a3" denotes the amount of subscription and "p3" indicates the unit of duration (that is, M = monthly, D = daily and so on). To make the subscription recurs indefinitely, set "src" and "p3" to 1.

For reference, you can read on PayPal documentation link here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HI00JQU

Comment: what if i want to subscribe multiple product with this form?